# Android progress bar memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, progress-bar

I have a progress bar being updated(with setProgress()) from an android CountDownTimer every 100ms. For some reason, whenever the timer is running, in the android memory graph, there appears to be a memory leak (A steady increase). Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
final int waitTime = Integer.parseInt(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
            .getString("answer_view_time", "2000"));
    final int countFrom = timerWidget.getProgress();
    CountDownTimer answerTimer = new CountDownTimer(waitTime, 100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //count up the time for the user to see his answer from where the timer had just left off
            timerWidget.setProgress(countFrom +(int) ( ( ( (waitTime - millisUntilFinished) ) / (float) waitTime )
                    * (timerWidget.getMax() - countFrom) ) );
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mQuiz.next();
            setQuestion(mQuiz.getCurrent());

            btn1.setEnabled(true);
            btn2.setEnabled(true);
            btn3.setEnabled(true);
            btn4.setEnabled(true);

            findViewById(R.id.main_conteiner).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_colored));
        }
    }.start();
```

This leaks in the timerWidget.setProgress(...); line. If I comment it out, the leak stops.

**Update:**
I can't find any reason for this to be happening. Even in one activity, when updating the progress bar through a loop, there seems to be a memory leak. Maybe it's a bug in Android itself? I am using Android 5.1 on a Lenovo device.

Comment: It would be nice so see some code.

Comment: You are right. I edited my post

Comment: How are you declaring the timerWidget?

Comment: It is a reference to a progress bar from my layout xml, initialized in the onCreate() method with findViewById(...);

Comment: Can't see any issues as such. Try polling a little less frequently maybe? Store `timerWidget.getMax()` outside the `CountdownTimer` code maybe...

Comment: I think this is an android memory leak, i have seen this as well. As long as the progressbar is running, memory used steadily increases.

Comment: Yes @TylerPfaff, Even a simple progressbar in Activity or Fragment leaks constantly increasing memory. This is totally unexpected and unattended bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you have is that your anonymous CountDownTimer class has a references to the class it was declared in (variables countFrom and waitTime).  This means that the outer class will never be garbage collected as long as the CountDownTimer exists.  If your not explicitly killing CountDownTimer onPause or onDestroy of this Activity/Fragment, you'll have many Outer Class and Anonymous CountDownTimer references that are never garbage collected each time you reload the timer.

Don't use countFrom and waitTime references in your anonymous class (instead create function getCountFrom(), getWaitTime()) - same for mQuiz, btn1, etc. Don't reference class variables outside your anonymous class directly.

For more info - http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html

> [Inner Classes] Moving on, let’s say we define a class inside the definition of our Activity’s class, known as an Inner Class. The programmer may choose to do this for a number of reasons including increasing readability and encapsulation. What if we create an instance of this Inner Class and maintain a static reference to it? At this point you might as well just guess that a memory leak is imminent.
>
> [Anonymous Classes] Similarly, Anonymous Classes will also maintain a reference to the class that they were declared inside. Therefore a leak can occur if you declare and instantiate an AsyncTask anonymously inside your Activity. If it continues to perform background work after the Activity has been destroyed, the reference to the Activity will persist and it won’t be garbage collected until after the background task completes.

Comment: I no longer have the source code for this project, so I cant test this - it's been a year since I asked this question. Thanks for the answer though, it is good to know.